# How to redirect using object results in the redirect URL?

Tags: javascript, url, redirect, replace

I am collecting data from a user on Server A,

I need to send that data in a URL to server B (separate buildings and companies)

On server A it is a CRM system which is pre built and I cannot just simply use PARAMETERs as I cannot HASH the PARAMETERs as the system is pre built by a third party and they would charge to allow for this.

So I have managed to build some JS that replaces certain characters from the PARAMETERs I can collect.

Here is a small snippet of what I have to make my HASH.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Collect USERID
var m = 'XX784188';

// HASH USERID
m = m.replace(/7/g, 'M');
m = m.replace(/4/g, 'S');

// Set up Object n as Location name.
var n = 'Cumbria';

// Rename Location to correct code
n = n.replace(/[Cumbria]/g, '01');

// Test Object m & n
alert(n);
alert(m);​​
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/LXMTM/) is the above in a test.

Now what I cannot seem to find out is how do I insert the results into a url and redirect the user to that URL.

For example:`http://google.com/?n=&m=`

I can insert this line I know for the redirect:

```
window.location = "http://google.com/?n=&m="
```

I just need to know how I make that URL look like this `google.com/?n=01&m=XXM8S188`

Answer (score 1):

Funny, I just answered the same thing 1min ago :

```
window.location = "http://google.com/?n="+n+"&m="+m
```

Comment: If n or m happen to contain special characters, a slight variation could help, like this: ...+encodeURIComponent(n)+"&m="+encodeURIComponent(m)

Comment: Ok I have tried this method and I get a page error. Like so:     This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 2540: EntityRef: expecting ';'
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet code and JS Fiddle code are different.

For **snippet code** then you simply insert your values like,

```
window.location = "http://google.com/?n="+n+"&m="+m;
```

For **JSFiddle code**, then,

```
window.location = "http://google.com/?"+serialiseObject(obj);​
```

Comment: I tried your first suggestion like the above answer and I get  the error as per my above comment. I had tried the JSFiddle code and nothing happens at all.

Comment: What I have found is the error on the page occurs because of the & symbol... Any thoughts on what the character encode on java is for that for if encoding it will help?